# How to query using Regex for the ISSN format pattern?

Tags: sql, regex, t-sql

Using Regex with T-SQL, trying to get a query that will select records that match the ISSN pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Serial_Number

That is 4 digits, a dash and either 4 digits or 3 digits and a letter X, for example:

1234-5678
or
1234-567X

X can be lowercase.

I tried:

"\d{4}-\d{3}(\d|x|X)"

```
SELECT [KBID],  [ISSN]
FROM [ISSNTable] 
WHERE  [ISSN] LIKE '%\d{4}\-\d{3}(\d|x|X)%'
order by ISSN desc
```

But it comes back empty.

If I try this:

> WHERE
>      [ISSN] not LIKE '%\^d{4}-\d{3}(\d|x|X)%'

The it returns everything in the table even badly formatted data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

T-SQL `LIKE` is a pattern matcher but not a regex pattern matcher.

```
DECLARE @issn varchar(9)
set @issn = '1234-567X'
SELECT 
CASE WHEN @issn LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][-][0-9][0-9][0-9][X0-9]'
    THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
END AS isValidISSN
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Tsql supports only rudimentary regex of character classes - no repetition expressions `{n}` or shortcuts like `\d`.

Try this:

```
SELECT [KBID], [ISSN]
FROM [ISSNTable] 
WHERE [ISSN] LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9xX]%'
order by ISSN desc
```